# Why doesn't this work? Calling functions belonging to objects in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object

In my code jsc.tools is an object containing objects. Each sub-object contains a init() and run() method.

I have the following code running at startup:

```
for(tool in jsc.tools) {
    tool.init();
}
```

which gives me the error "tool.init is not a function".

A sample of a tool's declaration is:

```
jsc.tools.sometool = {};
jsc.tools.sometool.run = function() {
    // Apply tool
}
jsc.tools.sometool.init = function() {
    // Set bits of data needed for the tool to run
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The for in x operator in javascript gives you the names of the properties off an object. Try:

```
for(tool in jsc.tools) {
    jsc.tools[tool].init();
}
```

Comment: This has caught me quite a few times too. You'd think the for(x in ..) would set x to the object/array/string/whatever, but it only sets x to the key.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
for(tool in jsc.tools) {
    jsc.tools[tool].init();
}
```